# Caesar cipher with GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, caesar-cipher, tkinter

I have created a functional Caesar cipher in Python 3 and I have implemented a GUI using Tkinter.

```
def MOST_COMMON_LETTER():
    return("e")

def circle(l,n):
    if n < (len(l) - 1):
        return(l[n])
    else:
        return(l[n % (len(l))])

def most_frequent(l): # not whitespace
    l = l.replace(' ','')
    all_frequencies = [l.count(i) for i in l]
    for i in l:
        if l.count(i) == max(all_frequencies):
            return(i)

def my_formatting(string):
    for i in string:                                     
        if i in ".,1234567890?!;:_;-/()[]{}+-*\"'":
            string = string.replace(i,'')               
    string = string.lower()
    return(string)

def en_de_code(string,key,en_or_de): #calling with en is encode, calling with de is decode
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    new_string = ""
    string = my_formatting(string)
    for i in string:
        if i == " ":
            new_string += " "
        else:
            position = alphabet.index(i)
            if en_or_de == 'en':
                new_string += circle(alphabet,position + key)
            elif en_or_de == 'de':
                new_string += circle(alphabet,position - key)
    return(new_string)

def encode(string,key):
    return(en_de_code(string,key,"en"))

def decode(string,key):
    return(en_de_code(string,key,"de"))

def randomly_encode(string):
    import random
    key = random.randint(1,25)
    return(encode(string,key))

def brute_force_decode(string):
    new_string = ""
    for key in range(1,26):
        new_string += decode(string,key)
        new_string += '-'
    return(new_string)

def meaningful_decode(string):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    the_most_frequent = most_frequent(string)
    key = -(alphabet.index(the_most_frequent) - alphabet.index(MOST_COMMON_LETTER()))
    return(decode(string,key))

def GUI():
    try:
        import Tkinter as tk
    except:
        import tkinter as tk

    master = tk.Tk()

    master.wm_title("Caesar cipher")

    key_label = tk.Label(master, text="Key")
    key_label.pack()

    key_slider = tk.Scale(master, from_=1, to=25, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,length=300)
    key_slider.pack()

    text_label = tk.Label(master, text="Enter your text down here")
    text_label.pack()

    text_field = tk.Text(master)
    text_field.pack()

    def allow_to_paste(string):
        master.clipboard_clear()
        master.clipboard_append(string)

    def encode_and_show():
        temp1 = encode(text_field.get("1.0","end-1c"),key_slider.get())
        result.set(temp1)
        allow_to_paste(temp1)

    b = tk.Button(master, text="Encode", command=encode_and_show)
    b.pack()

    def randomly_encode_and_show():
        temp2 = randomly_encode(text_field.get("1.0","end-1c"))
        result.set(temp2)
        allow_to_paste(temp2)

    b = tk.Button(master, text="Randomly encode", command=randomly_encode_and_show)
    b.pack()

    def decode_and_show():
        temp3 = decode(text_field.get("1.0","end-1c"),key_slider.get())
        result.set(temp3)
        allow_to_paste(temp3)

    b = tk.Button(master, text="Decode", command=decode_and_show)
    b.pack()

    def brute_force_decode_and_show():
        temp4= brute_force_decode(text_field.get("1.0","end-1c"))
        result.set(temp4)
        allow_to_paste(temp4)

    b = tk.Button(master, text="Brute force decode", command=brute_force_decode_and_show)
    b.pack()

    def meaningful_decode_and_show():
        temp5 = meaningful_decode(text_field.get("1.0","end-1c"))
        result.set(temp5)
        allow_to_paste(temp5)

    b = tk.Button(master, text="Meanigful decode", command=meaningful_decode_and_show)
    b.pack()

    result = tk.StringVar()
    result.set("Encoded text")

    paste_information = tk.Label(master, text="Just paste to en/de-coded text where you want it.")
    paste_information.pack()

    result_label = tk.Label(master, textvariable=result)
    result_label.pack()

    tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI()
```

- Is it understandable the first time you read it?
- Does it make use of "black magic" (absurd expressions that only who used them in the first place knows)?
- Should I explain briefly what my function do with a doc-string?
- Should I use a Class for the Tkinter GUI part?
- Is there something that is just bug-prone or considered bad style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ```
   def MOST_COMMON_LETTER():
       return("e")
   ```

   This should be just a variable, not function.

   ```
   MOST_COMMON_LETTER = "e"
   ```
2. ```
   def circle(l,n):
       if n < (len(l) - 1):
           return(l[n])
       else:
           return(l[n % (len(l))])
   ```

   For simple code, we can eliminate the first branch - the % operator does the work for us. Also need better namings:

   ```
   def cycle_get(lst, index):
       return lst[index % len(lst)]
   ```
3. ```
   def most_frequent(l): # not whitespace
       l = l.replace(' ','')
       all_frequencies = [l.count(i) for i in l]
       for i in l:
           if l.count(i) == max(all_frequencies):
               return(i)
   ```

   Here you do a lot of iterations, because `l.count()` iterates through the whole list/string. I would suggest using `Counter`. Also comment is worse than a good function name, let's name the function `most_frequent_letter`. Also your implementation does count punctuation and other non-letter symbols, though they are quite rare in real texts. Also for CAESAR cipher case is not meaningfull, so we need to strip it.

   ```
   import string
   from collections import Counter


   def most_frequent_letter(text):
       counts = Counter()
       for c in text:
           if c in string.letters:
               counts[c.lower()] += 1
       return counts.most_common(1)[0][0]
   ```
4. ```
   def brute_force_decode(string):
       new_string = ""
       for key in range(1,26):
           new_string += decode(string,key)
           new_string += '-'
       return(new_string)
   ```

   It's better to return list of possible decryptions, not concatenation with "-". If you need to display it - it's better to concatenate right before the display (e.g. `'-'.join(decryptions)`.

   ```
   def brute_force_decode(string):
       decryptions = []
       for key in range(1, 26):
           decryptions.append(decode(string, key))
       return(decryptions)
   ```

   Or even better, use list comprehension:

   ```
   def brute_force_decode(string):
       return [decode(string, key) for key in range(1, 26)]
   ```
5. ```
   def meaningful_decode(string):
       alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
       the_most_frequent = most_frequent(string)
       key = -(alphabet.index(the_most_frequent) - alphabet.index(MOST_COMMON_LETTER()))
       return(decode(string,key))
   ```

   `alphabet` should be moved to the top and be capitalized (convention, so other people would suppose it's constant). Also in `most_frequent_letter` function you would be able to use your `ALPHABET` instead of `string.letters`.
6. The GUI function.

   - It is better to move imports to the beginning. Thus import errors will occur at the earliest time. Also people look for imports at the beginning to see which libraries are used.
   - I would suggest splitting the function into a couple of smaller functions. E.g. create_labels, create_buttons., or create objects depending on the visual grouping.
   - There is some redundant code with `.pack()`, but it seems that it is the badness of the Tkinter API. Except for buttons, you give them bad names which are immediately overwritten:

     code:

     ```
     b = tk.Button(master, text="Encode", command=encode_and_show)
     b.pack()
     ```

     I would replace such things to:

     ```
     tk.Button(master, text="Encode", command=encode_and_show).pack()
     ```

   Except these notes, GUI function looks quite good.

Comment: Is it considered good practice to use 'return' without parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, it is. This allows to distinguish language operator from a function, and also is less verbose.

Comment: `alphabet` could just be [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase). (For that to work, you have to take care not to name the parameter `string`, which would shadow the module name.)

Answer (score 6):

### UI issues

- It's not obvious where the input text box is.  It has no border or colour difference until it gains focus (which is difficult if you don't know where it is).
- It's not obvious where the output is.  I would expect the output to be as prominent as the input — after all, it will contain just as much text.  I would also want it to be a read-only text area so that I can select text and copy it to the clipboard.
- The buttons could be laid out better than than in a one-column arrangement.

### Algorithm

`en_de_code()` is an awkward function name, and `en_or_de` is an awkward parameter.  I would just define `decode()` in terms of `encode()`.  The interpretation that comes to mind is "English or German?"

```
def encode(string, key):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    new_string = ""
    string = my_formatting(string)
    for i in string:
        if i == " ":
            new_string += " "
        else:
            position = alphabet.index(i)
            new_string += circle(alphabet, position + key)
    return new_string

def decode(string, key):
    return encode(string, -key)
```

Comment: Good answer, just one remark _I would also want it to be a read-only text area so that I can select text and copy it to the clipboard._ it is automatically copied to your clipboard.

Comment: I have implemeted your suggestions, if you are interested in the result, it is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxW2x7KJABOASXhXZkZDcWVrcHc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I would still want to be able to select specific text within the output, or re-copy it if I overwrote the clipboard.

Comment: I implemented the output as a disabled text field and my programme looks nicer. Sadly you can't right click and select to paste something, after you select you must Control-C, do you know a workaround around this?

Comment: It makes sense that you can't paste into a disabled (read-only) text area.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, you can right click and select copy, so that _in the future_ you will be able to paste the data from the disabled test-box.